# XSS issue raised on http://localhost:3000/packs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, owasp, zap

I am testing a rails app for `XSS` issue using `OWASP ZAP`'s UI. The app is using `Webpack` for handling assets (javascript, css, fonts, etc). After performing the attack/scan I get a XSS issue that uses a `GET` request on `http://localhost:3000/packs`.

Since it is a `GET` request I thought the app might've accidentally exposed such endpoint. I tried to go to that URL on the browser, but the red rails red error page confirms that *No route matches [GET] "/packs"*.

I expect not to see such a security issue on `ZAP`. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1):

Very difficult to say without more information.
Its very likely that an attack vector used by ZAP has been reflected in the HTML on that page.
That doesnt necessarily mean its an XSS, you would need to satisfy yourself one way or another.
If you do find that its a false positive then please raise this as an issue on the ZAP repo so that we can hopefully fix it.